# A for loop isn't counting the amount of characters generated correctly

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
import random
y = 0
while True:
    input('press enter to generate')
    for x in range(25):
        y = random.randint(0,1)
        if x == 5 or x == 10 or x == 15 or x == 20 or x == 25:
            print(f'{y}')
        else:
            print(f'{y}',end='')
```

and here is the resulting output:

```
press enter to generate
011011
11011
00000
01101
1011press enter to generate
```

im trying to make it clean and in a 5x5 layout and i've tried changing the amount of repeats in the loop and the position of the newlines.

desired output:

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

numbers can be 1/0

Comment: can you show us what is the desired output? what would you like it to look like?

Comment: @snatchysquid will add an edit

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/fca27d2f) is a clean version of your code for now, you might want to use this instead

Comment: It is simpler with two loops (rows and columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counts you're checking are off by one.  `range(25)` runs from `0` through `24`, so the last element of each row occurs at 4, 9, 14, 19, and 24.  You can fix it with:

```
if x == 4 or x == 9 or x == 14 or x == 19 or x == 24:
```

or more simply:

```
if x in (4, 9, 14, 19, 24):
```

You could also do:

```
if (x+1) % 5 == 0:
```

Comment: why not use `%` (modulu)?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the for loop altogether by using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
while True: 
    input('\npress enter to generate')
    y = np.random.randint(0,2,25).reshape(5,5)
    print(np.array2string(y).
        replace('[',' ').replace(']','').replace(' ',''))
```

Output:

```
press enter to generate
10001
01010
10100
01010
10111
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `range` to `range(1, 26)`:

```py
y = 0
while True:
    input('press enter to generate')
    for x in range(1, 26):
        y = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x % 5 == 0:
            print(f'{y}')
        else:
            print(f'{y}', end='')
```

You can use `x % 5 == 0` instead of what you have.

Comment: press enter to generate
0
00010
00110
11100
01110
11101

press enter to generate

that was the output from that code

Comment: @7abc778 What do you mean? The code above works as expected.